# TCP Comm: How is the receiver notified for new data when working with large data packet sizes?

Tags: sockets, tcp, winsock

Say there is a TCP connection established between 2 partner A and B. Both of them use WinSocket (or whatever API) . Now one calls the send() api function setting the length to 100kByte in order to send his application data.
I understand that those 100kByte can be chucked up into any number of messages on TCP protocoll level and that TCP will take care that all those chunks will be appended at receiver side in the right order. What I try to figure out is how often will the receiver be notified that there is new data available. Will WinSock wait until the complete payload (-> 100kB) is received, then set the respective socket and allow the application to fetch the whole data packet at once or can it be that the application may get the data bit by bit thus has to do internal buffering itsself if it needs to comsume the 100kByte at once?

The messages I send look sth like this:
   MsgHeader | Payload

Thus I rely on receiving one complete message at once. If it would be bits and pieces instead it would mess up my message handling.

I know that TCP is stream oriented and that a message oriented protocoll (UDP?) probably would better fit my needs. However i wonder if I'll be OK using TCP.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know much about WinSocket, but in java, you get an InputStream from the Socket, and specify at most how many bytes you want to receive in one call to InputStream.read(). But the number of bytes actually received is dependent, so you need to create your buffer to fill up the message. One example may exist in InputStreamReader, which implement readLine().

Comment: @GordonLiang `DataInputStream.readFully()` is a more relevant example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your code. Call `recv`, appending the data you received onto any left over from the previous call. If you don't have an entire message, call `recv` again until you do. If you do have an entire message, process it, saving any leftover data for the next pass.

Don't use UDP. If you use UDP, you will need to implement yourself all the things that you need that UDP doesn't do such as reordering, retransmission, slow start, exponential backoff, and so on. That's a lot more work than just writing proper receive logic to parse messages from a byte stream.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation. The contract of `recv()` in blocking mode is that it blocks until at least one byte has been transferred, or EOS or an error occurs. Nothing there about blocking until the buffer is filled.

If you want messages, you have to implement them yourself. TCP is a byte-stream protocol.

Comment: If the specify the `MSG_WAITALL` flag to `recv()`, it blocks until the requested buffer is completely filled.

Comment: True, but you really should almost never do that. No protocol can work if both sides are allowed to wait for the other. Most protocols allow the sender to wait for the receiver, so they cannot also allow the receiver to wait for the sender.

Answer (score -1):

As a programmer you can always check how fast you receive data, this is my c# example, but i think you'll get the gist of it:

```cs
var stopwatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

read = sr.Read(buffer, 0, packetSize); //attempt to read whole thing in one go
while (read < packetSize) //if it failed, read until you've read the whole thing
    read += sr.Read(buffer, read, packetSize- read); //read only as much as you need

stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds); //check how long it took
```

`sr` is stream object used for read/write operations. From my observations the read value is different even if i send exact same packet of data, so I guess it depends on OS. Try out TCP or UDP connection, see which is better for you. If you send large packets of data frequently, then UDP will be better because it will create less overhead data.

Comment: He didn't ask about how fast, and this code doesn't check for errors, so it will loop forever if an error occurs. It also doesn't advance the offset correctly, or check the termination condition correctly either.

Comment: This is a simple example and you can easily check how much you've read each time, which is part of the answer to whether the app could read the whole thing at once.

Comment: It's a *wrong* example. Three separate bugs, at least, and the part about timing is irrelevant.

Comment: It's an example that works. I've copied it from my testing code that i was using just today for exact same purpose. It's not meant to be used in final application, only to check out how much data you can grab and how much time does it take

Comment: @CoreMeltdown: It works until something fails, like a dropped connection. EJP is 100% correct. Learn from the comments instead of just trivializing them.